Expo StoreReview is spamming the user on Android
In my project I use expo's StoreReview.requestReview(). Which should use Android's ReviewManager.
I call the requestReview() method after user logs in. And I do not want to spam the user after every login, if he clicks on the "not now" button.
In the ReviewManager docs i found this:

public abstract Task launchReviewFlow (Activity activity,
ReviewInfo reviewInfo)


Launches and displays the review flow to the user.
Note: In some circumstances the review flow will not be shown to the user, e.g. they have already seen it recently, so do not assume that calling this method will always display the review dialog.

By reading the docs, I assumed that I do not need to control when the user will be prompted with the review dialog, because ReviewManager's launchReviewFlow handles that by default.
I tested it only on beta environment, I noticed some differences between prod and beta env. eg. the review text is required but on prod it should be optional.
So my question is - is this handled on prod by the Android's ReviewManager or do I need to control it myself ?
I tried calling requestReview() and expected that the Android's ReviewManager will handle the duration between showing the dialog.
